# makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable crashing app on real device with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play

I am running makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable on Android 4.2.2 on a real device and it just crashes with the stack trace below.  I dont know if this is a makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable issue or something more from the error message? This same code works fine on an emulator with higher Android OS.

```
public class EventsActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability =  GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int success = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(success != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            googleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);
    }
```

Error

```
Process: com.exposure, PID: 5713
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.EventsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1560)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:696)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:667)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabm.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaw.zzc(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaw.zzs(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabb.zzu(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The problm is you're calling it from a destroyed activity.  More than that we can't tell without code.

Comment: Added code, as I said its on startup and not destroying anything.

Comment: Try calling it after super.onCreate().  Until that's called the Activity isn't really initialized.

Comment: Ha that was it, curious why it didnt work on my emulator but it seems good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling it after `super.onCreate()` fixed the problem.